# image not taking full width on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I am using bootstrap in my webpage and when I view my page on a small screen, ex iPhone7, the image in it gets very very small, I tried using @media but it is not working, can someone please tell me, what I am missing
here is my code for the CSS and html

```
<img src="example" style="width: 40%; margin: 0 auto" class="img-responsive img-center" alt="Responsive image">

@media (max-width: 768px) {
            .img-responsive {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
```

Comment: remove inline css `width: 40%;` from `img`  tag

Comment: The reason I am making it 40% at the beginning is that I want it to not take the full width on bigger screens, so is there another way ?

Comment: you can create another class for this instead of using inline css

Comment: because browser applies inline css first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your very best to avoid inline styling. You need a default width for the `.img-responsive` class, and a media query to target smaller screen for a 100% width.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awzvVB

```
<img src="example" class="img-responsive img-center" alt="Responsive image">

.img-center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.img-responsive {
  width: 40%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

BTW, you will need to set the image as a block element (`display: block`) in order to center it with `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this worked, now I understand how the custom scaling for different screens works

Answer (score 0):

Don't target `img-responsive` class.
add another class or ID and apply css with `!impoprtant` at the end.